# Admin in AppEngine App

Tags: google-app-engine

I was just confused who are considered admin in an AppEngine application? Roles I can see in Administration/Permission are Owner, Developer and Viewer. Are these 3 are the admin of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those 3 are administrators. An administrator is a user who can access the Administration Console for the application. You can use the Administration Console to manage which users have administrator status.

The difference between owner, developer and viewer, are the permissions on the admiration console.